# How to connect to MongoDB Database via IP

Tags: node.js, mongodb, digital-ocean

I have a simple question, but can't find a working solution.
I have an app that runs on Vue and Mongo. I've used Mongo Atlas for testing, but it's time for the app to go on prod, so decided to go with DigitalOcean. I've created droplet with Node.js and MongoDB and managed to connect my backend and MongoDB. But!
When I run my file on the VPS there is no issue:

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname', { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    app.locals.db = client.db('xxxx');
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
})
```

However, when I'm trying to connect via IP on my local copy I got timeout-ish error.

```
mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://ip:27017/dbname', { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    app.locals.db = client.db('xxxx');
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
})
```

I've tested with `ip:3000` (the port of the app) and `ip:27017`. Also, I've created a user and tried with user and pass. Same thing. I've tried to edit **mongod.conf** and along localhost I've added the VPS's IP - still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried whitelisting all addresses?

Comment: Yes. Actually I found the issue 2 minutes after I published the question here. It turned out that right after the **host:port** part I was provided the path to the project instead of the database name. They have similar names...

Comment: mongod by default only listens on 127.0.0.1, did you make sure it is listening on the other IPs?

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the IP address in the configuration file.

You are mentioning `ip:3000` parameter , rather it should be `BindIP : 3000`.

For more information please refer to the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html

you can also refer to a blog which I found good to solve the similar problem.

https://medium.com/@mansi.kapahi/setting-up-a-mongodb-replica-set-on-an-ec2-server-e32c4d0f0849